# Generator that ensures minimum distance between two items in a list

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to make a script that takes the content of a file, stores it into a container, and then pseudo-randomly takes a row from the container.

The file contains a song lyric, a hashtag, and a link, separated by a /t, but I'm trying to make the code elastic to any change - adding or removing an element from the row.

The issue is with the pseudo-random generator, that I shamelessly copied, and don't really understand.
I got that the issue is that the matrix isn't a hashable type, while in the generator I'm using the set() to hash it.
How do I fix the code of the generator for a matrix? Supposedly, it should choose a row randomly, but avoiding to choose the same one again too closely.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random, collections, time

# Pseudo-random generator
def choice_gen(choices, min_dist):
    last_choices = collections.deque(maxlen=min_dist)
    choices = set(choices)
    while 1:
        c = random.choice(list(choices - set(last_choices)))
        last_choices.append(c)
        yield c

# Organizes the contents of the file in matrix 
# <Song lyric> <hashtag> <link>
songs_table = []
with open("songs.txt") as f:
    for txtline in f:
        song_data= txtline.split('\t')
        songs_table.append(song_data)

# Prints a pseudo-random row of the matrix
for song_data in choice_gen(songs_table,2):
    print "{}".format(song_list)
    time.sleep(2)

# With dictionary, only 2 values per song though,
# the script runs without issues here
# <Lyric> <hashtag>
"""     
song_dict = {}
with open("songs.txt") as f:
    for txtline in f:
        (key, val) = txtline.split('\t')
        song_dict[key] = val

for line in choice_gen(song_dict.items(),2):
        print "{}".format(line)
        time.sleep(2)
"""
```

Comment: And what is the traceback you get then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list` objects are mutable, thus not hashable. Use tuples, which are not mutable thus hashable:

```
songs_table = []
with open("songs.txt") as f:
    for txtline in f:
        song_data= tuple(txtline.split('\t'))
        songs_table.append(song_data)
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> some_nested_list = [['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']]
>>> set(some_nested_list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> set(tuple(el) for el in some_nested_list)
set([('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), ('spam', 'ham', 'eggs')])
```